# Lookup for a value different than 0 in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm interested how can I find a value different than 0 in Excel?
For example, I have:

```
ID Value
1  0
1  2
2  10
3  20
```

If I do a vlookup, for ID 1 it will bring me 0, because it's the first value found by the vlookup.
I'm interested in getting 2(as value) for ID 1.
I know..I can make a sum by ID and then again a vlookup. Any other ideas?

Comment: you can use SUMIFS: `=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,1,B:B,">"&0)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `XLOOKUP()` which support lookup from last to first but you can also have `0` at last value. So, `FILTER()` can give you correct result. Try-

```
 =FILTER(B2:B5,(A2:A5=1)*(B2:B5>0))
```

[image]